# django queryset limited choice filed by FK

Tags: django-filter

I have two models

- Notification
- Asset

To display data using the django-filter.
Unfortunately, when you create a form in the select-field all the values of the model Asset, and I would just those related to FK model Notification.

```
 def get_queryset(self):
    try:
        self.filter = NotificationListFilter(
            self.request.GET,
            queryset = Notification.objects.all()
        )

        return self.filter
    except :
        return Notification.objects.order_by('-asset__system')
```

In some way I can build queryset this to happen?